# Update is throwing Insert The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: database, .net-core, hangfire

I have a Hangfire background job that updates users in my database. When the code is run, it throws an exception

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. The conflict occurred in database table column

I'm not sure why its throwing an `Insert` error when I'm calling `Update`. Any ideas whats causing this error?

Background job:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("updateUsers")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUsers(var user)
{
      BackgroundJob.Enqueue<UserController>(x => x.UpdateUsersFirstMiddleLastName(user));

      return Ok(true);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUsersFirstMiddleLastName(var user)
{
    var userDto = GetUserInfoViaLDAP(user.UserName);

    var displayName = userDto.displayName;
    var tempName = displayName.Split(" ");

    user.DisplayName = displayName;
    user.FirstName = tempName[0];
    user.LastName = tempName[2];
    user.MiddleInitial = tempName[1];

    _userService.Update(user);

    try
    {
        await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw ex;
    }
   
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Comment: There may be a smarter way to troubleshoot this, but if I were faced with this exact problem right now, I'd run a database trace to figure out what's really going on on the database side.

Comment: Is there a database trigger which fires upon UPDATE and INSERTs *something*, *somewhere* (and violates foreign key constraint)?

Comment: @Littlefoot yes your thought was on the correct path. My SaveChangesAsync call is an overriden method that is inserting values to my AuditHistory table which is the same table throwing the error